# Delete Line in footer

Tags: ms-word

I have a word document with a number of sections that I'm  to fix (remove all page numbers, give it one page across the sections,etc). I however noticed that there is this line  is the footer in the 2nd section and beyond that just wont go away.

I can't select to delete it. 
Can't drag it up and down either (it seems to be at the same level as the top margin in the footer so changing this margin changing the vertical position.

I dont really know what it is so searching with text like "word 2010 delete line in footer" did not  prove very useful. Using Word 2010.

regards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem may occur if both of the following conditions are true:

```
The line was created by typing a series of 3 or more characters and then pressing ENTER. The characters include the hyphen (-), underscore (_), equal sign (=), asterisk (*), tilde (~), and number sign (#).

-and-
The AutoFormat As You Type feature in Word is configured to automatically format borders.
```

**RESOLUTION**

To delete the line, follow these steps:

```
Click at the beginning of the line.
On the Format menu, click Borders and Shading, and then click the Borders tab.
Under Settings, click None, and then click OK.
```

Comment: I'm using 2010. Does not have a format menu. How do I do this in 2010?

Comment: Tried it and it worked in some scenarios.

Comment: For 2010 and later just set the border to be None under Home->Paragraph

Comment: NOTE: it works (thanks!) but the funny thing is that in the ribbon it seems that no border is set. I had to open explicitly the borders menu to find the line.

Answer (score 1):

Under page layout tab, go to page border and in it go to border and apply none. you can also change its format by applying the new one and by applying it to the paragraph